# Replace a font-awesome icon with another one for all the appearances inside an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, font-awesome

For getting all the elements containing that specific icon one should write:

```
const elementList = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-line-chart');
```

this creates a list which can be looped with a foreach, the problem is that I cannot update it with the new icon.

I've tried to do it like:

```
elementList.forEach(document => document.style.icon= '.fa-pie-chart');
```

Comment: Could you show how the sample element looks like?

Comment: your must change your code like this `elementList.forEach(document => document.classList.add('fa-pie-chart');` It wasn't work because you put the className `.fa-pie-chart` as a value of icon property of the document style

Comment: shouldn't I remove the first class too?

Comment: I wanted to know what are the classes in the elements. so that remove only specific classes can be done before adding the classes again.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
$('.fa-line-chart').each(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('fa-line-chart');
  $(this).addClass('fa-pie-chart')
});
```

### EDIT

If I understand your question, maybe you are trying to change the icon fa class for all icons that meet some criteria?

In this case, I would use `.toggleClass()`

For example (taken from [jquery api](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-function-state)

```
$( "div.foo" ).toggleClass(function() {
  if ( $( this ).parent().is( ".bar" ) ) {
    return "happy";
  } else {
    return "sad";
  }
});
```

This example will toggle the happy class for  elements if their parent element has a class of bar; otherwise, it will toggle the sad class.

Comment: you are right in some way. this does that but I want to do it with a querySelector implied so the changing of the class takes place only inside a function

Comment: Would `.toggleClass( function [, state ] )` work? Then you can provide a function as a test to determine whether to toggle the classes or not.

Comment: there are 8 elements that must be changed from `fa-check-square` to `fa-square` on it

Comment: I tried your method but it still modifies the element on my page but not inside the function it should do it. I''m using this code inside a function which exports that data to an image, and that modification should be available only on the export. this approach works in the opposite way for me: it changes the class on the page but doesn't change it in the export

Comment: How are you exporting? jQuery is meant for DOM traversal - if you want to change the DOM, but I don't think that's what you want here.

Comment: Maybe what you need is to clone the element which you are exporting `.clone()` then run my original code only on the cloned element, export that and then `.remove()` it